# reactjs formik despite clearing all value one value is showing up when clicked on someother component

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, components, formik

ive created a custom textfield in react formik. while using textfield in some other components and enter something and clearing all values and clicking somewhere else, only first value (of cleared word) is showing up.
so the textfield component have a input tag
so after entering any word in this example if i type "John".
clear everything in field now its blank.
select some other field
the field is now showing "J". despite clearing everything

```
class CustomInputComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focused: false
    };
    this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
  }

  onFocus() {
    this.setState({
      focused: true
    });
  }

  onBlur() {
    this.setState({
      focused: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      type,
      title,
      field,
      label,
      customClass,
      readOnly,
      customInputStyle,
      maxLength,
      ariaLabel,
      ariaLabelBy,
      autoComplete,
      htmlFor
    } = this.props;
    let fieldClass = `form-control form-control-danger ${styles.inputField}`;
    if (customClass) {
      fieldClass = `${fieldClass} ${customClass}`;
    }
    // console.log('field.value', field.value);
    const inputContainerClass = this.state.focused || (field.value && field.value !== '') ? styles.inputFocused : styles.inputBlur;
    const labelClass = this.state.focused || (field.value && field.value !== '') ? styles.labelFocused : styles.labelBlur;
    return (
      <div className={inputContainerClass}>
        <label htmlFor={htmlFor} className={cn(labelClass, styles.customLabel)}>
          {label}
        </label>
        <input
          {...field}
          type={type}
          title={title}
          value={field.value || ''}
          className={fieldClass}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
          onBlur={this.onBlur}
          disabled={readOnly}
          style={customInputStyle}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          aria-label={ariaLabel}
          aria-labelledby={ariaLabelBy}
          autoComplete={autoComplete}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

reusing the above component in child

```
import {customInputComponent} from ***
const randomComponent = () => {
 const getInitialValues = () => {
  let values = {};
  values = {
    guestName: '',
  }
  return values;
 }
 const formComp = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
     <customInputComponent guestName={guestName} />
    </Form>
  )
 }
 return (
 <Formik 
   render={renderData => formComp(renderData)}
   initialValues={getInitialValues()}
   onSubmit={handleSubmit}
   enableReinitialize
 />
)
}
```

so after entering any word in this example if i type "John".
clear everything in field now its blank.
select some other field
the field is now showing "J". despite clearing everything